# how to view segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: gdb, segmentation-fault

I am unable to move forward in getting to see the core dumped.

I have got this when i typed

```
gdb normal_estimation core


Reading symbols from /home/sai/Documents/pcl_learning/normal_estimation/build/normal_estimation...(no debugging symbols found)...done.

warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
[New LWP 11816]

warning: Can't read pathname for load map: Input/output error.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./normal_estimation'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0xb53101d6 in free () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb)
```

Please let me know what should i do?

Comment: `no debugging symbols found`: that's a hint. Enable debugging when compiling your code (disabling optimizations also helps a lot with debugging).

Comment: i have compiled the file using make. How can i give debugging symbols

Comment: No, you have compiled your code using a compiler (most probably gcc). Read its documentation to find out about how to use it.

Comment: i used cmake and then make

Comment: cmake and make just invoke your compiler. You need to tell them how to pass appropriate options for your compiler. Since you haven't provided any info about your makefiles, it's up to you to figure that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
>   `#0  0xb53101d6 in free () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`

The first command you need to learn is `backtrace` (or its synonym: `where`).

This will tell you which code invoked the `free`, which crashed.

However, it is possible that that code has nothing to do with the actual problem: any crash in `free` is always caused by heap corruption of some sort (freeing un-allocated memory, freeing the same memory twice, writing to memory that has already been freed, or overflowing an allocated buffer).

The most useful tools to diagnose heap corruption on Linux are [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) and [AddressSanitizer](http://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/AddressSanitizer). Chances are either of these tools will tell you *exactly* what you are doing wrong.

Comment: This is GDB report.


[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./normal_estimation'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0xb53101d6 in _obstack_allocated_p (h=0xb5498d18, obj=0xbfe6ca90) at obstack.c:341
341 obstack.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb53101d6 in _obstack_allocated_p (h=0xb5498d18, obj=0xbfe6ca90) at obstack.c:341
#1  0xbfe6cab0 in ?? ()
#2  0x08087c5c in main ()
(gdb)

Comment: I tried valgrind and it gave this summary. ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Comment: one more thing...when i see on web, all programs are compiled using g++ or gcc but here i have a CMakeLists.txt and thus I do cmake and then make. SO I am not able to properly use the resources from web